# Join two tables in mysql and return multiple rows (first table contains one row and second table contains multiple rows)

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, arraylist, jdbc

I have two tables

```
table-1
|stdid  | stdname | 
|-------|---------|
|1      | raghav  |
|2      | sowmya  |
|3      | kiran   |
```

```
table-2
 | skillid | stdname |  skill |
 |---------|---------|--------|
 |  1      | raghav  |  java  |
 |  2      | raghav  |   c    |
 |  3      | raghav  |   c++  |
 |  4      | sowmya  |  python|
 |  5      | sowmya  |   c++  |
 |  6      | kiran   |    c   |
```

I want output like

```
raghav c,c++,python.

Soumya python,c++.

kiran c.
```

How can join those two tables like this and store them in `Arraylist`

Does `Arraylist` accept array variables? if yes how can I approach it?

Comment: Why do you need to join? All results can be obtained from `table-2`.

Comment: Let's say you want to join. Do you also need "." at the end or is it end of statement in the required output?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and then aggregate by name:

```sql
SELECT t1.stdname, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.skill, 'NA')) AS skills
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.stdname = t1.stdname
GROUP BY
    t1.stdname;
```